# Android - Take a picture not working

Tags: android, image, android-intent, camera, save

I'm trying to make a simple app: 
I made a button, its onClick should call the camera intent, save the picture in the internal storage and then i want to put the picture in a custom listview gallery... for now I haven't made the listview because I'm having problems with the intent. the camera doesn't open and I don't know why even if the right permissions are in the manifest file

any help is appreciated, I've tried a lot of tutorials but I can't find the problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "LOG_TAG" ;
public static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1; /* ci serve la richiesta per la camera*/
private Button btCamera;
private Button btSavePicture;
private ImageView imageViewShowPicture;
private File imageFile;

/*attributi per salvare foto*/

private String savePicturePath;

/*_____________________________________________________________________________________________oncreate*/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /*Collego oggetti alla grafica*/
    btCamera = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btCamera);
    btSavePicture = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btSalvaFoto);
    this.imageViewShowPicture = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ivMostraFoto);

    /*listener*/
    btCamera.setOnClickListener(this);
    btSavePicture.setOnClickListener(this);
}

/*___________________________________________________________________________________________metodo TAKE A PHOTO*/

private void startTakeAPictureIntent(){
    Intent takeAPictureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    }}

/*___________________________________________________________________________________________metodo crea image file*/

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    savePicturePath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

/*______________________________________________________________________________________metodo aggiungi alla gallery*/
private void addPicToGallery() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(savePicturePath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

/*______________________________________________________________________________________metodo decodificare un'immagine scalata*/
private void setPic() {
    // Get the dimensions of the View
    int targetW = imageViewShowPicture.getWidth();
    int targetH = imageViewShowPicture.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savePicturePath, bmOptions);
    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW/targetW, photoH/targetH);

    // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(savePicturePath, bmOptions);
    imageViewShowPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

/*_____________________________________________________________________________________________onclick*/
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
       case R.id.btCamera: {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ho premuto btcamera");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           startTakeAPictureIntent();

            /*Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, RICHIESTA_FOTOCAMERA);*/

        } break;
        case R.id.btSalvaFoto:{
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ho premuto btsalvafoto");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "salvafoto clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

/*_____________________________________________________________________________________________onActivity result*/

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) { /* se la richiesta mi da risultati*/
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap immagineBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data"); /* prendi gli extra */
        imageViewShowPicture.setImageBitmap(immagineBitmap); /*setto la imageview per mostrarla*/
    }

}
```

}// chiude activity

Comment: Are you using a real android device or emulator?

Comment: a real device,  if in the OnClick I only write

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

the intent works, but if i use the methods i wrote in my first message  it doesn't work

maybe there is an error in the onClick?

Comment: Did you add logs to see where exactly its going and if it is resolving the intent as null? Do some base level analysis on what you are assuming should be.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add following permission and see.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Please refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#manifest to see anything other you need to declare.

Comment: my permissions are already ok
I have logs but they only say if I have clicked the button